# Rename table in mRename table in mysql if other table is empty

Tags: database, bash, mariadb

I have two table with name"A" and "B" and same data.
Every day at 00:00 table A updated ( they frist drop table A and replace new data on this table).
Some time network problem caused table A stay empty.
How can rename table B to A at 00:10 when table A is empty?

Comment: Please, take the time to read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and to learn how to write a good quality questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If conditional in SQL Script for Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384711/if-conditional-in-sql-script-for-mysql)