# applying database patches via mercurial hooks

Tags: mysql, mercurial, alter-table, mercurial-hook

I'm currently trying to determine how to apply mysql database patches via mercurial commit hooks.  Basically, I have an incoming commit hook pointing to some script in my search path.  This all works.  My real question is how do keep a series of mysql alter table statements that can be applied every time I pull (incoming mercurial hook), that won't error when run again.  For instance:

I add a new column to a table.  So in my altertables.sql I add something like:

```
ALTER TABLE `thecompany_tbl` ADD `firstLogin` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1';
```

I run this the first time via the automated commit hook.  Works fine.  Next time I pull, it will try and run this again, and yield something like:

```
#1060 - Duplicate column name 'firstLogin'
```

Anyway around this?  It would be great if I could just keep a file with all the alterations and then apply it every time I pull.  Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter your script so that it doesn't make the change if it has already been applied.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395798/mysql-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-table-with-sql) answer shows how to check if a column exists.

Alternatively, you could add a table to the database to contain a version number that the script checks and updates.  That might be easier as the other option involves checking each type of change with a different query.