# How can I check if a column exists into a table from a database?

Tags: mysql

I have a huge database and a column name that I am not sure if it exists in any of my tables.
How can I check its existance?

Comment: VladH indicated below on my answer that this is what he was looking for - if the question could be reworded to reflect this, I feel it would be less broad.  He even specified that his issue was not knowing which table exactly held the column.

Comment: I edited your post in order to keep everything clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name'

AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'`

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395798/mysql-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-table-with-sql

Comment: cheers dude! the problem was that I didn't know the name of the containing table but apparently " SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name' " worked.

Comment: Yeah, you can edit the `WHERE` clause to suit your needs - glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check all tables, you may have to list the tables first:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM database_name;
```

Then, loop through the tables (in code, e.g., PHP), and execute this query:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM database_name.table_name LIKE 'mycol';
```

This will return a result if the column exists on the table.

You can also select directly from the information_schema, but I have found this to be very slow in some cases with MySQL and large databases.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('columnA','ColumnB')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';

please check above code with your database
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME ='table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'col_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the information schema

```
select *
from information_schema.tables
where table_name = 'employee'
and table_schema = 'test';
```