# How do I check whether column exists in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to check whether `mytable` table is containing `mycolumn` column? Here is my query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable LIKE mycolumn) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

But it doesn't work and throws this error-message:

> **#1064** - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable LIKE mycolumn) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END at line 1

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Refer this `http://stackoverflow.com/a/24194492/2845151`

Comment: I am deleting my comment...

Comment: It is strange you think you need to check this with an SQL query. You should *know* what columns are in your tables.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes that's kinda odd ..! But actually I'm creating a dynamic query and sometimes I need to check `x` column exists or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following as an if

```
IF EXISTS(
    select * from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME ='SOMETABLE' AND
    COLUMN_NAME = 'SOMECOLUMN')
)   
BEGIN
     -- do stuff
END
GO
```

Alternatively as a case

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    select * from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME ='TABLE_NAME' AND
    COLUMN_NAME = 'COLUMN_NAME') 
Then 1 Else 0 End;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name') 
then 1 
else 0 
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass the Table and Column name dynamically , please use this.

```
DECLARE @Table Varchar(100)
DECLARE @Column Varchar(100)
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)

SET @Table ='MyTable'
SET @Column ='MyColumn'


SET @Query ='select * from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME ='''+@Table+''' AND
    COLUMN_NAME IN ('''+@Column+''')'

EXEC (@Query)
```

Comment: I really don't want to do that `:-)` .. Thx anyway +1