# SQLITE : Check if column exists without trigger an error in php

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

My situation is this:

- I have an array that contains the names of the columns of a table
- I must, with a loop , iterates through the array and check if that field (this column name) exists in the table
- If it exists, I do not do anything, otherwise I have to add

  ```
  $array_column = ["column1 NOT NULL","column2 NOT NULL","column3 NOT NULL","column4 NOT NULL"];

  for($j = 0 ; $j < count($array_column) ; $j++){

    $query = "SELECT ".$array_column[$j]." FROM my_table";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    $check = false;
    //try{
       foreach ($result as $row) { //error here
          $check = true;
       }
    //}catch (Exception $e) {
      //echo "here";
      //$check = false;
    //}

    if(!$check){
      echo "column [".$array_column[$j]."] to add <br>";
    } 

  }
  ```

But when I find a column that does not exist in the table, php gives me error

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach ()
```

I also tried a TryCatch, but the same error.
I wish that php did not return that error when it doesn't finds a column

### UPDATE 1 :

i try this , it works, but unfortunately not when there are no records in the table

```
$select = $db->query('SELECT * FROM mytable');

$total_column = $select->columnCount();
var_dump($total_column);

for ($counter = 0; $counter <= $total_column; $counter ++) {
      $meta = $select->getColumnMeta($counter);
      $column[] = $meta['name'];
}
print_r($column);
```

### UPDATE 2 : This solution works perfectly, even if there are no records in the table!

```
$result = $db->query("PRAGMA table_info(test2)");
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$meta = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
   array_push($meta, $row['name']);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL, Check if a column exists in a table with SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395798/mysql-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-table-with-sql)

Comment: Not a duplicate @Phantom because of the way that you have to get the data back from SQLite vs. the way you would with MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

PRAGMA table_info('table_name') will return a list of row ( one for each column on your table)
Unfortunately you can't use it in a select query but you can parse it and try to look for your column name before querying on your table.
Hope that's help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sqlite_fetch_column_types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-fetch-column-types.php) function to get an array with the column names of your table. This array can then be used to in your loop.

Comment: $db = new PDO('sqlite:info.sqlite3');
$cols = sqlite_fetch_column_types('telecamere', $db, SQLITE_ASSOC);

//Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_fetch_column_types()

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? Depending on which version you might need to [install this extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php) if possible.