# Check if a field exists and it's not null

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to fetch a value from a table with three possibilities: 1) The field exists and it's not null, so it returns the value of the field 2) the field exists but it's null, so it returns is-null-string 3) The field doesn't exists, so it returns not-existing-string

I am trying to run this query but I get this error message *`#1054 - Unknown column 'm.my_field' in 'field list'`*

```
SELECT if (exists(SELECT *
                  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
                  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'my_field'
                 ), IFNULL(m.my_field, 'is-null-string'), 'not-existing-string'
       ) AS my_field,
       m.*
FROM my_table m
```

Any idea how can I get it done in mysql 5.6?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943905/3900932

Comment: Something is highly suspicious about your application/data model if you don't know if a column is in a table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I agree with you. But I was wondering if there is a solution to get this result without having to change the tables.

Comment: @MohammadMehdiHabibi . . . In general, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`DESCRIBE`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-show-columns/):

```
DESCRIBE my_table;
```

Look at the result to see if your field exists. Note, you don't want this code to be in your application. You need to know your table fields to run queries. You might only use this to generate some boilerplate code.