# Add a column if it does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

Using `Sqlalchemy`, I try to add a `column` to a `table` if it doesn't exist:

```
mytable = ticker +"data"
connection.execute("alter table "   + mytable    + " add column IF NOT EXISTS tokeep boolean;")
```

But I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS tokeep boolean' at line 1")
[SQL: alter table ABTdata add column IF NOT EXISTS tokeep boolean;]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

Comment: Consider using a tool like alembic for schema changes; this doesn't look like the sort of change you should need to change on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN`  has **no** `IF NOT EXTSTS`

See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

```
  | ADD [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
        [FIRST | AFTER col_name]
  | ADD [COLUMN] (col_name column_definition,...)
```

What you can do is check if such a column exists
see for example [MySQL, Check if a column exists in a table with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395798/mysql-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-table-with-sql)

or use  a `try`in sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1):

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html and notice that `IF NOT EXISTS` is not supported syntax for `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN`.

Your options are:

- Check if the table contains that column first, before you attempt to add it.
- Try to add the column. It will return an error if the column already exists. Handle the error.
- Try using a metadata management tool like [Skeema](https://www.skeema.io), which analyzes your current table structure and the desired table structure, and generates the ALTER TABLE needed to ensure the columns you want are present.